# Having issues with checking if a user exists in db (MERN stack)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

---

Hi guys I'm doing my first full-stack MERN application and I've been trying everything to check if a user already exists (by either .exec() or using a callback function) in my database but I keep running into request errors (500 etc), code is below. I need your help geniuses!!!!

---

'userModel.js'

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// new user model for mongo
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}, 
{
  collection: 'users'
})

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

'users.js'

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const userModel = require('../models/userModel')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// POST users to db
router.post('/', (req,res) =>{

  // new instance of user model to be mutated
  const User = new userModel({
      // grabbing user register data and pushing to mongo
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
  })

  // checking if user already exists
  User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, async function(err, user){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if(user){
      console.log('user exists')
    }
    else{
      const newUser = await user.save()
      res.json(newUser)
      console.log("username: "+ req.body.username + ", password: " + req.body.password)
      /*catch (err) {
        err => {res.json({message: err.message})}
      }*/
    }

  })
})

module.exports = router;
```

'app.js'

```
// Connect to database
const db = require('./bin/mongoURI').mongoURI;

mongoose
  .connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log('CONNECTED TO MONGODB'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that are wrong with your code, here are the explanations:

#### 1) Take advantage of `mongoose` framework

Instead of searching for a User that exists under the same username, you can take advantage of the `unique` property from mongoose. It will not allow you to post a user which `username` already exists in your DB.

That way, you can get rid of your call to `findOne()` which in turn, reduces the total response time of your endpoint. You can read more [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematypeoptions_SchemaTypeOptions-unique).

Your schema would then look like this:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true        // here
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}, 
{
  collection: 'users'
})
```

#### 2) Do not confuse `Model` and `Document`

In your `users.js` file, you wrote this:

```
const User = new userModel({
      // grabbing user register data and pushing to mongo
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
  })

  // checking if user already exists
  User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, [...]
```

By writing `const User = new userModel([....])`, you declare a **document**, which is an instance of a **model**. On the next line, you attempt to call the method `findOne()` on this document, which is never going to work since this is a method from the **models**. You can read more about that [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#documents-vs-models).

You should've written instead:

```
const User = new userModel({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
  })

  // NOTE HERE the use of userModel, instead of User
  userModel.findOne({username: req.body.username}, [...]
```

#### 3) async/await, try/catch and how I would write your `router.post` route

You are using a `callback` syntax while also using `async/await` syntax:

```
User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, async function(err, user){[...]
```

which is very confusing.

Now, I don't know if the combination of the two is even possible since I've never tried it, but it might be source of errors. I recommend sticking to one of the two, at your liking (although I prefer `async/await` myself).

You can also take advantage of `try/catch` blocks, to gracefully handle errors and send feedback to your user even if something went wrong in the execution of the code.

Here is a full example (**non-tested**, mind you) of how I would've done it, keeping most of your structure not to confuse you:

```
// Note the use of async right before (req,res)

router.post('/', async (req,res) => {
  try {
    // You don't actually need to precisely fill the constructor, mongoose will complain if anything is out of place
    const User = new userModel(req.body);

    const newUser = await user.save();
    console.log("username: "+ req.body.username + ", password: " + req.body.password);
    res.json(newUser);
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle here any kind of problem, be it ValidationError or more
    return res.status(400).send({error: 'Oops, something went wrong'});
  }
});
```